# .NET Azure SDK - Blob request returns 400 BadRequest

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the latest Azure SDK Nuget package which is 3.0 released today and trying to work with Blob storage locally in my development environment.  I created a blob in my local development storage using Azure Storage Explorer and am trying to read the data but getting a 400 Bad Request returned.  When I dig into the response object returned by the exception it is saying "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format."

The strange thing is that when I put the full URL in a browser it downloads the blob just fine (http://xxx.x.x.x:10000/devstoreaccount1/test/722b6bea-d609-48e0-a4af-3ed0f5160ad9)

Here is the code I am using:

```
        var storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("722b6bea-d609-48e0-a4af-3ed0f5160ad9");
        var text = blob.DownloadText();
```

I also tried creating a new blob in code and am getting the same exception

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably this post may help you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b1b66cc0-5143-41fb-b92e-b03d017ea3c1/400-bad-request-connecting-to-development-storage-using-azure-storage-client-ver-20?forum=windowsazuredata

**Update**

As pointed out by Gaurav Mantri in the comments:

> Don't use Storage Client library 3.0 as it makes use of latest storage
>   service version which is not yet supported in storage emulator. Based
>   on the **[blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx)** by storage team, support for
>   latest storage service version in emulator is coming in couple of
>   months.

Comment: I have the latest .NET Azure SDK installed which is 2.2 as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure it's the same issue.  Unless for some reason the new NuGet package which is 3.0 doesn't work with the latest version of the emulator which is 2.2.

Comment: Looks like the Azure Storage NuGet package version 3.0 released today does not play well with the Azure SDK for .NET 2.2 which is the latest one I can find to install.  When I downgraded back to the 2.1.0.4 NuGet package it started working as expected.  I'm guessing a new SDK will come out soon that will fix this but for now I'll have to not upgrade so I can work locally with Blob storage.

Comment: Don't use Storage Client library 3.0 as it makes use of latest storage service version which is not yet supported in storage emulator. Based on the blog post by storage team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx, support for latest storage service version in emulator is coming in couple of months.

Comment: @Nitin - When posting an answer, you should post details of the solution, not just a link.

Comment: @David - Next time I would surely take care of it.

Comment: @GauravMantri "fixed" my issue -- the new storage client not working with the 2.2 SDK emulator.  Pff.

Comment: This problem cost me so much time. Released without support for the main test environment - ouch!

Comment: the emulator is out now http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41670